# Create function returns double value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to make some function in phpmyadmin

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION total_bayar (order_id char(10)) 
RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist double;
  SET dist = SELECT sum(qty * price) FROM detail_masakan WHERE order_id = order_id;
  RETURN dist;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Query SQL: Dokumentasi

```
CREATE FUNCTION total_bayar (order_id char(10)) 
RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE dist double;
  SET dist = SELECT sum(qty * price) FROM detail_masakan WHERE order_id = order_id;
  RETURN dist;

END
```

MySQL says: Dokumentasi

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT sum(qty * price) FROM detail_masakan WHERE order_id = order_id;
>     RETURN' at line 6

Comment: You should not give parameters the same name as column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses for the subquery:

```
SET dist = (SELECT sum(qty * price) FROM detail_masakan WHERE order_id = order_id);
```

However, this still won't do what you want, because the variable names are messed up -- and will get confused with the column names.

I would suggest:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION total_bayar (in_order_id char(10)) 
RETURNS double
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE out_dist double;

  SELECT out_dist := sum(dm.qty * dm.price)
  FROM detail_masakan dm
  WHERE dm.order_id = in_order_id;

  RETURN out_dist;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears it didn't like your use of the SET command.  Use SELECT...INTO instead.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE FUNCTION total_bayar (order_id char(10)) RETURNS double 
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE dist double; 

    SELECT sum(qty * price) INTO dist FROM detail_masakan WHERE order_id = order_id; 
    RETURN dist; 
END// DELIMITER ;
```